# Clear all browsing data in Safari

Tags: macos, safari, password

In Edge, Chrome, Firefox, I can clear all browsing data which lets me delete everything, including history, cache, cookies, site permissions, page zoom, passwords, form data, etc, all in one click.
Settings obviously aren't reset.

In Safari, I can clear history, but that is very incomplete.
Passwords are retained.
If I go to Settings - Websites, the websites from the previous sessions are still listed.
The entries under Privacy - Website Data do seem to get cleared.

How do I clear all browsing data, similarly to Edge, Chrome and Firefox?